# How to export/share my personalized styles on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, style

I created a lot of personalized styles for QGIS and my co-workers are asking me to share the styles with them. How can I export my personalized styles of lines, areas and points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the style manager (Settings>Style Manager...) and choose the symbol to export, they are saved in a XML file that you can share with your co-worker

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Layer/properties, style tab : choose style button/**save style** and save it as QGIS layer style file `(.qml)` or `(.sld)` file ...
Store and share as u want ...